# A simple cloud function to write to database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am attempting to write my first cloud function. Here is the function that I have deployed.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

exports.onMsgAdded = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/messages/{to_uid}/{msg}').onCreate((snap, context) =>{
    const data = snap.val();
    const msgRoot = admin.database().ref('/users/' + context.params.to_uid + '/messages/' + context.params.uid);
    return msgRoot.set(data);
});
```

The problem is this does absolutely nothing. It is being triggered as I can see it in the functions dashboard, but the write is not being executed.

Here I only have one user in the database. When a message is created, I want to copy it to the to_uid's user 'messages' node.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried logging all the various values in your function to see if they are what you expect them to be?

Comment: yes. the bottom screenshot is my attempt at running it after deploying the function and nothing.

Comment: I got it :-| so easy.  Thanks Doug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to add admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.onMsgAdded = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}/messages/{to_uid}/{msg}').onCreate((snap, context) =>{
    const data = snap.val();
    const msgRoot = admin.database().ref('/users/' + context.params.to_uid + '/messages/' + context.params.uid);
    return msgRoot.set(data);
});
```

DERP

Comment: You should update you firebase functions and admin and use`admin.initializeApp()` instead of `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)`